# Setting custom image view as action bar's menu icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I would like to add one of the menu icons of the action bar as below.

[image]

I need an icon and a bubble on top of that and I need to display a number on that at run time.
Is it possible to do? I have Googled regarding this, but couldn't find exact way to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you want is call **"badge"**

A simple way to "badge" any given Android view at runtime without having to cater for it in layout.

try this Lib

> https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Comment: Link only answers are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define custom layout for your action bar as mentioned in the tutorial [here](http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/actionbar-header-tutorial/)
and to display counter above the Imageview android notification class can be used.